# C++ threading model for creating multiple instances of class spawning threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, architecture, pthreads

Abstract:

I am designing a class (`Inner`) which spawns 2 threads- a producer and a consumer. In one usage there is one instance and in another context there are multiple instances.

In Standalone I need the two threads to continue writing/reading messages. However, if there's multiple instances I need the code to spawn the two threads but continue to create the next class (to spawn more threads).

My problem is trying to combine these two scenarios with correct usage of `std::thread::join()` and `std::thread::detach()`.

Code details:

The class `Inner` spawns a thread to receive and queue messages and a second thread to read the queue and send messages to the class owning `Inner`.

```
template<Owner>
class Inner
{
    Inner(Owner& owner) : _owner(owner)
    {
        // Spawn thread to receive packets and put on queue
        // Spawn thread to read from queue
    }

    void receiveMessage(const Message& msg)
    {
        // Ommitted locks etc for simplicty
        _queue.push(msg);
    }

    void readFromQueue()
    {
        // Ommitted loop, locks etc for simplicty
        _owner.receiveMessage(msg);
    }

    Owner& _owner;
    std::queue<Message> _queue;
};
```

There are two possible owner classes, `SingleInner`:

```
class OneInner
{
    OneInner()
    {
        _inner = std::make_unique<Inner>();
    }

    void receiveMessage(const Message& msg){//Code ommitted}

    std::unique_ptr<Inner> _inner;
};
```

and the second context has multiple instances:

```
class MultipleInners
{
    MultipleInners()
    {
        // Need to create multiple instances of Inner, each with Inner's two threads running
    }

    void receiveMessage(const Message& msg){//Code ommitted}

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Inner>> _inners;
};
```

I'm unsure how I can allow `Inner` to spawn 2 threads, have them keep running but in `OneInner` the code waits and in `MultipleInners` the code continues to create the next `Inner`.

Or if there's a completely better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource of which you need one for each instance of a class, and who's lifetime is the same as that of the matching instance is best represented as a member variable.

So just make the threads member variables of `Inner` that are launched at construction, and joined at destruction:

```
template<Owner>
class Inner
{
    Inner(Owner& owner) 
      : _owner(owner)
      , _recv_thread([this](){readFromQueue();}),
      , _read_thread([this](){receiveLoop();}),
    {
    }

    ~Inner() {
      _recv_thread.join();
      _read_thread.join();
    }

    void receiveLoop() {
      while(...) {
        //etc...
        receiveMessage(msg);
      }
    }

    void receiveMessage(const Message& msg)
    {
        // Ommitted locks etc for simplicty
        _queue.push(msg);
    }

    void readFromQueue()
    {
        // Ommitted loop, locks etc for simplicty
        _owner.receiveMessage(msg);
    }


    Owner& _owner;
    std::queue<Message> _queue;
    
    // Make sure these are the last members, so that _owner and _queue 
    // are constructed already when the threads start
    std::thread _recv_thread;
    std::thread _read_thread;

};
```

Comment: This works. Unfortunately I have to pass an argument to receiveMessage() which is Google Protobuf and I think they've made it non-copyable etc, so have a few additional headaches to cure.

Comment: @user997112 Yeah, sorry, I think `receiveMessage()` is not the right thing to pass to `_read_thread`, you probably want whichever function has the main loop for that thread. I'll ammend the answer,

Comment: Out of the scope of the question but: Are you even sure you need a dedicated receiving thread for each `Inner`? That sounds a bit unusual. Whatever thread produces the messages can just invoke `receiveMessage(msg)` directly itself.

Comment: Also: Protobufs are not copyable, but they should be movable without much trouble.

Comment: I've put the receive loop in another class. So my list initializer lambda looks like this:

`): _receiveThread([this](const GoogleProtobuf& gpb){_udp.listen(getPortsAddresses(std::move(gpb)))})`

However, i'm getting `static assertion failed. std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues`

Comment: I'm just mocking it up in Godbolt and will share the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235669/discussion-between-frank-and-user997112).